# SQL Return Only 1 row per FieldID

Tags: mysql, sql, flutter

I have table called 'mytable' with this schema:

- wordID  INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
- wordLV  VARCHAR(100),
- wordENG VARCHAR(100),
- field   VARCHAR(40),
- fieldID INTEGER  NOT    NULL
- type    VARCHAR(1),

I need to make objects called Field who have properties( fieldID, field). 
And I have a lot of inputs - 1250, but there are only 33 different fields, so that means that most of them appear more than 1 time. How can I get all my 33 fields and not more??

Comment: Have you tried the Select Distinct ?

Comment: You could provide sample data and expected output based on 3 different fields and scale up any answer that fits your requirement.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!

Comment: I think SELECT DISTINCT works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
it takes the distinct combination of the field_id and combines it with the field to a string.

```
select distinct concat(fieldID, ", " ,field) from mytable;
```